# botão enviando submit mesmo ao cancelar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

tenho um botão em ASP.NET webForm e mesmo clicando em cancelar ele envia o submit.

**Exemplo no Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/qywvuhvq/

```
    $(function () {
        $("[name='chk_IDDel']").change(function () {
            var disabled = true;
            $("[name='chk_IDDel']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    disabled = false;
                    if ($("input[name=chk_IDDel]:checked").length > 1) {
                        document.getElementById("<%= btn_Deletar.ClientID%>").value = 'Deletar imóveis';
                 }
                 else {
                     document.getElementById("<%= btn_Deletar.ClientID%>").value = 'Deletar imóvel'
                 }
             }
         });
         $('#<%= btn_Deletar.ClientID%>').prop("disabled", disabled);
     });

     $("#<%= btn_Deletar.ClientID%>").click(function () {
         var confirma = prompt("digite a palavra 'confirmar' para deletar", "");
         if (confirma.toUpperCase() == "CONFIRMAR") {
             document.all.submit();
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     });
 });
```

O que estou fazendo de errado no JQUERY? não quero que envie ao clicar cancelar..ou não digitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de juntar `event.preventDefault()` para impedir o submit da form uma vez que esse input tem `type="submit"`.

Sugiro juntares isso e corrigires também o código para o caso do "cancelar" ser clicado e com isso a variável confirma não receber nenhum valor dando erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null` pois não consegue chamar  método o `toUpperCase()` numa variável que tem valor `null` (e não *string*).

Sugiro ainda mudares `document.all.submit();` para `document.querySelector('form').submit();` ou se tiver um ID usa o ID. Podes também usar `$(this).closest('form').submit();` que tem a vantagem de ser específico a essa `<form>`.

Testa assim:

```
$("#btn_Deletar").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var confirma = prompt("digite a palavra 'confirmar' para deletar", "") || '';
    if (confirma.toUpperCase() == "CONFIRMAR") {
        document.querySelector('form').submit();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1oaju47/1

Comment: por algum motivo ele esta funcionando, mas parou as funcionalidades do ASP:Button (não esta executando o código)

Comment: removi o e.preventDefault(); esse da problema no WebForm
e funcionou
http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/qywvuhvq/1/

Answer (score 2):

Em nenhum momento o seu código impede o envio do formulário, para fazer isso você deve chamar o método `preventDefault()` do evento passado como parâmetro da função criada em `.click()`

```
$("#<%= btn_Deletar.ClientID%>").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // continuação do seu código
}
```